# send output signal via analog output channel

Tags: matlab, signals, channel

I wrote a script to generate sounds with random intervals, and every time a sound is generated I want to send an output signal to a DAQ device using the appropriate analog output channel. However when I record from the specified channel I don't record any change in voltage while I would expect a rectangoular pulse of 1 sec (as specified in the for loop)

```
%Identify the device
devices = daq.getDevices
devices(5)
s = daq.createSession('ni')
addAnalogOutputChannel(s, 'Dev1', 'ao0', 'Voltage');
outputSignal = 0;
%sound specification
values = 0:1
startle_sound = 3*sin(2*pi*16000*values)

%Generate n random number between t_max and t_min
n = 5;
t_min = 10;
t_max = 20;
times = t_min + rand(1,n)*(t_max)
for t = times
    pause(t); %// Pause for t seconds   
    sound(startle_sound)
    %send signal to MoCap system
    t_out = 0:0.1:1
    d = 0:1;
    outputSignal = pulstran(t_out, d, 'rectpuls'); %rect pulse

end
```

Comment: Is the signal not generated, or you just can't seem to capture it in MATLAB? I suppose you have some oscilloscope (or even some speakers) in your lab, using which you can rule out the former. In case it's the latter, it becomes a question of whether the input is "always recording" and somehow buffered, in which case when you request a second of data, it just gives you whatever is found in the buffer, which might not be what you want. Alternatively the "interesting stuff" happens while you generate the sound (synchronously), so when you get to record it - you already missed it!